# How to show data conditionally to record values in form view odoo 16.0

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-16

I am trying to show info that depends of the model values in form view

```xml
<t t-if="record.id"> ...
<t t-if="record.name == 'Anon'"> ...
<t t-if="name == 'Anon'"> ...
```

Record and name are undefined

```xml
<record id="custom.model_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">custom.model.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">custom.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Model">
            <sheet>
                <field name="name" />

                <t t-if="record.id">
                    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                    <button string="Test Button" name="action_test" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                </t>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attrs` to set `invisible` attribute based on condition. You can find an example in [stock](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/stock/views/stock_orderpoint_views.xml#L151) module where a button is hidden when the `id` field is not set:

```py
attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '=', False)]}"
```

Comment: If i need conditions to values?
<h1 t-attf-class="#{id ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}">Hello world!</h1>
<h1 t-attf-class="{{'text-success' if name == 'Anon' else 'text-danger'}}">Hello world!</h1>

Comment: Duplicate it and use `attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '!=', False)]}" class="text-success" ` and `attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '=', False)]}" class="text-danger" `